# Django app_label with spaces - leads to 404 error in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I've been trying to customize the name of the app that is displayed and have run into an issue when using spaces in app_label, it results in a 404 error page when I try to visit the url. For example,

```
app_label = 'Occupational Therapy'
```

results in the text displaying as I intended, but visiting that url in the admin site gives the following, though the pages for individual models appear correctly. Example: url/admin/Occupational%20Therapy/ returns this:

```
 Page not found (404)
 Request Method: GET 
 Request URL: url/admin/Occupational%20Therapy/
```

but url/admin/Occupational%20Therapy/model displays everything correctly.

I've tried using this:

```
app_label = 'occupational_therapy'
```

as the django documentation seemed to state that it would be capitalized and strip out the underscore automatically, but the underscore remains, as Occupational_Therapy is what is displayed. In this case, the urls work perfectly so if there is a way to strip out the underscore, that would really solve the problem. Otherwise, I assume I would need to edit the urls.py file?

Comment: The admin is not your app. It should only be used for trusted admins, and you should write views for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.app_label) is used to indicate which Django application a model belongs to and not to alter the URL. If your application was named `polls` you could for example place models into `polls\models\voting.py` and into `polls\models\results.py`. The models would then need:

```
app_label = 'polls'
```

I don't know how to change the URLs for applications in the Admin site. Changing them on other parts of the site should be done using `urls.py`.